# Can't open file No such file or directory in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Currently I am trying to implement `taoxugit/AttnGAN` work on the birds dataset. I have uploaded the project on drive and imported it to Colab.

```
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/drive')

     %cd /content/drive/MyDrive

!unrar x "/content/drive/MyDrive/fashiongen/AttnGAN-master1.rar" 

%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/AttnGAN-master1/AttnGAN-master
```

But when a try to run below line I get the following error

`!python pretrain_DAMSM.py --cfg cfg/DAMSM/bird.yml --gpu  python3: can't open file 'pretrain_DAMSM.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I can see the file in `/content/drive/MyDrive/AttnGAN-master1/AttnGAN-master/code/pretrain_DAMSM.py`
but don't know why I'm getting this error. I'm also getting an error for bird.yml

```
    import os
    os.chdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/AttnGAN-master1/AttnGAN-master")
    os.getcwd()
```

I used this code to set path. but no use still getting error. Now I entered the full path.

```
    !python /content/drive/MyDrive/AttnGAN-master1/AttnGAN- 
     master/code/pretrain_DAMSM.py --cfg /content/drive/MyDrive/AttnGAN- 
     master1/AttnGAN-master/code/cfg/DAMSM/bird.yml --gpu 0
```

but now getting another error

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

'../data/birds/CUB_200_2011/bounding_boxes.txt'

I can see the text file in specified folder but don't know why colab cannot find any file.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide the full path to the file because `cd` doesn't persist.

So it would be something like this.

```
!python /content/drive/MyDrive/AttnGAN-master1/AttnGAN-master/code/pretrain_DAMSM.py --cfg <full path to >/bird.yml --gpu
```

You must also get the path for the `bird.yml` file correct too. My suggestion is to find it using the Files view in Colab, then right click on it and do `Copy path`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did the same experiment and got a little insight.

The problem is that you did not enter the correct directory first, so the program cannot find the corresponding file according to the relative path. should be used like below:

```
%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/AttnGAN-master1/AttnGAN-master/code
!python pretrain_DAMSM.py --cfg cfg/DAMSM/bird.yml --gpu 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).